# Matrix representation with respect to a given basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I was given this question (in German), but I'm asked to find the representation matrix in respect to the standard basis. As far as I know I should preform the operation (the function) on all the elements of the basis (here it's a polynomial basis of degree 3). Then we rewrite the solution we get (of each) with the same basis elements. We take the corresponding coefficients and transpose and should get the answer. Seemingly simple. But I don't understand how they achieved this matrix. When taking $x$ cube for ex. I get a polynomial of degree 4? Did I understood the operation correctly with the derivative? What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: How did you compute $f(x^3)$? Remember that $p'(x - 1)$ means substitute $x - 1$ into $p'$, not multiply $x - 1$ to $p'(x)$. The result should definitely have degree $3$ when $p$ is degree $3$.

Comment: @TheoBendit thanks. I wasn't aware I should substitute into the derivative. I thought of simple multiplication.  How can one differentiate? In this case I knew something is wrong due to the limitations of the basis elements but otherwise how can one know? Is this a rule of thumb for those kind of operators/ derivative functions or writing in general?

Comment: The derivative is a polynomial, and we can substitute algebraic expressions like $x - 1$ into said polynomials. In the case of $p(x) = x^3$, we have $p'(x) = 3x^2$, which says $p'(x - 1) = 3(x - 1)^2 = 3x^2 - 6x + 3$. You then multiply $x$ to this to get $xp'(x - 1) = 3x^3 - 6x^2 + 3x$.

Comment: @TheoBendit I understand, was just curious about the notation in general. Thanks again.